# How to query a column in a table in all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wish to query a column in a table in every database that the table exists.  So far I have the following but am not sure where to go from here:

```
DECLARE @tblName VARCHAR(5000) = 'myTable'

SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE CASE
    WHEN state_desc = 'ONLINE'
        THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.[dbo].['+@tblName+']','U')
    END IS NOT NULL
```

So far I can return all databases with the table I am looking for but I want all the column data from a specific column in the specified table in every database on the SQL server.  Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You are on the right track. Use DYNAMIC SQL to write each select statement out.

Comment: Do I write it out in the THEN portion?

Comment: I like the sp_foreachdatabase as answered by Tab. If you prefer to do it this way.. here is the concept: Create a temp table of database names with an identity column (1,2,3,4,5). Then loop through each item in the temp table and write your new SQL statement combining each with a UNION... then execute your SQL statement. Like I said, the sp_foreach... seems a little easier :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sp_foreachdatabase makes a nice shortcut:   http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/

Answer (score 0):

`sp_MSForEachDb` can be buggy, skip databases and other weird stuff. There is an alternative procedure [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/) that has a very similar usage.

Another way would be

```
DECLARE @tbl SYSNAME = 'sys.objects'
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = CAST((SELECT 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.' + @tbl + ')' + 
                        ' SELECT TOP 1 ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''' db, * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.' + @tbl AS 'data()'
                FROM sys.databases
                WHERE database_id > 4
                FOR XML PATH('')) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))


EXEC (@sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use something like this

```
Create #tempTable(col datatype, col1 datatyep.....)
;EXEC sp_msforeachdb 'USE [?]
                    IF DB_NAME() IN(SELECT name
                                FROM sys.databases
                                WHERE CASE
                                    WHEN state_desc = ''ONLINE''
                                        THEN OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + ''.[dbo].[myTable]'',''U'')
                                    END IS NOT NULL)
                        INSERT INTO #tempTable
                        SELECT mycolumn from my table
                        '
SELECT * from #tempTable
```